# Variable not being changed

Tags: javascript, css

With the following code I am trying to move a small dot across the screen every time the document is hovered over.

The problem is that the "x.style.left" property which is initialized but not defined is updated the first time(I checked it with console.log) but after that it does not update any-more and remains at that value even though I changed it further in the code.

here is the code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("bot");
document.onmouseover = function(){move()};


function myfunc(){

}

function move(){
       x.style.position="relative";
       x.style.left;
       console.log(x.style.left);
       x.style.left=String(10 + 10) + "px";
       console.log(x.style.left);
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/puxg59td/

Comment: x.style.left is always going to be 20px.  how about Number(x.style.left || 0) + 20 + 'px'

Comment: you are only ever giving it a value of 20 and never increasing the value. When you say `x.style.left=20px` it's positioned from origin not from current position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the value and add to it each time.

```
function move(){
       x.style.position="relative";
       var value = parseInt(x.style.left);
       if (!value) {
           value = 0;
       }
       console.log(x.style.left);
       x.style.left=String(value + 10 + 10) + "px";
       console.log(x.style.left);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/puxg59td/1/

Answer (score 0):

Updated (Here is the jsfiddle update: https://jsfiddle.net/puxg59td/10/):

```js
var x = document.getElementById("bot");
document.onmouseover = function(){move()};

function move(){
    x.style.position="relative";
    var curLeft = parseInt(x.style.left) || 0;
    x.style.left= (curLeft + 10) + "px";
}
```

```css
#body{
    border:2px solid black;
    height:100px;
}


#bot{
    height:1px;
    width:1px;
    background-color:black;
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="bot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: parseInt, just as a heads up, will strip out the 'px' for you. You don't need to do replace.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment position. Your problem is that you always give x same 20px left style;
try this:

```
function move(x){
   x.style.position="relative";
   var l = x.getBoundingClientRect().left;
   console.log(l);
   x.style.left =l + 20 + "px";
   console.log(x.style.left);
}
```